# Call stored procedure from sqlplus

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, oracle11g

How to call a stored procedure from sqlplus?

I have a procedure:

```
Create or replace procedure testproc(parameter1 in varachar2,parameter2 out varchar2)
begin

Do something

end;
```

I tried exec `testproc(12,89)` ::Returns error

Comment: In general, it's better if you say exactly what error you're getting, instead of just saying it "returns error"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second parameter of your procedure is an `OUT` parameter -- its value will be assigned to the variable passed when the procedure completes.  So you can't use a literal value for this parameter.

You can declare a bind variable at the SQLPlus prompt and use that:

```
-- Declare bind variable
VARIABLE x NUMBER

-- If necessary, initialize the value of x; in your example this should be unnecessary
-- since the value of the second parameter is never read
EXEC :x := 1

-- Call the procedure
EXEC testproc(12, :x)

-- Print the value assigned to the bind variable
PRINT x
```

Alternatively, you can use an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
-- Activate client processing of dbms_output buffer
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

-- In anonymous block, declare variable, call procedure, print resulting value
DECLARE
  x NUMBER;
BEGIN
  testproc(12, x);
  dbms_output.put_line( x );
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   create or replace procedure autogenerate(t1 in int,t2 in int)
   is
   jum number;
   begin 
            if t1 < 10 then 
            dbms_output.put_line('Value too low.');
                else if t1 > 20 then 
                dbms_output.put_line('Value too high.');
                end if;
            end if;
   end;
   /
   show errors;
   set serveroutput on;
   execute autogenerate(1,2);
```

Try this, if you have question just post it again to me :)

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTSQLRULEPROC(param1 in varchar2, param2 out varchar2) AS
BEGIN

 IF TO_Number(param1) < 10 THEN
  param2:='Value too low.';

 ELSIF TO_Number(Param1) > 20 THEN
    param2 := 'Value too high.';
 
 ELSE
  param2:= 'NULL';
 END IF;

 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  param2:= 'Not a Number!';
  
END TESTSQLRULEPROC;